# What is the Diff between username/passwords and Bearer tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, access-control, bearer-token

According to RFC-6750 A security token with the property that any party in possession of the token (a "bearer") can use the token in any way that any other party in possession of it can **(without demonstrating possession of a cryptographic key)**.

- Q1) Isn't this definition applies to username and password also because **anyone in possession of a username and password** can use it in the **same way as any other party (maybe stolen the username & password) in possession of it can**? In both cases (without demonstrating possession of a
  cryptographic key). Is it because a token already contains permissions?
  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Both can be used by someone who steals them, as you say, but the key points about access tokens are that:

- They are short lived (~60 minutes), unlike passwords
- They represent only a subset of the user's permissions that a particular app needs

**STEALING ACCESS TOKENS**

Access tokens are also not easily stolen. An attacker may be able to get an access token for their own login, but that will not allow them to elevate their privileges in any way, if your UIs and APIs are coded securely.

**PASSWORD MANAGEMENT**

A stolen password is far more serious than a stolen token, since a password represents anything the user can do, possibly across many apps.

OAuth technologies keep passwords out of apps for the above reasons. Your app should never see the user's password and is not responsible for any password vulnerabilities.

Instead passwords are maintained by specialist Identity Provider software. Most commonly companies plug in a low cost cloud solution, where the password management has been developed by security experts.

Comment: Thank you. The thing that confused me was this statement "property that any party in possession of the token (a "bearer") can use the token in any way that any other party in possession of it can (without demonstrating possession of a cryptographic key)." And my view was that it applies to passwords also. Now you referring to access token. am I right to say that every access token is a bearer token?

Comment: Bearer tokens are by far the most common option, since they are what works for web and mobile UIs. Higher security options are possible in back end scenarios, such as [Mutual TLS to get a token](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8705/) or [Proof of Possession Tokens](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-pop-key-distribution-04.html), where the client sends proof of a private key in addition to the token itself. These are typically not feasible for web and mobile UIs though, since they are public clients and cannot keep secrets.